# Is there a way to use a variable to get the last X observations of an XTS dataframe in R?

Tags: r, xts

I'm trying to average the last X minutes of a dataset using a variable in R, I also do not know how to set my start date to today at midnight, so I've just plugged in 24 hrs from the enddate instead:

```
xts <- xts::xts(tempdat, order.by = data()$date)
    enddate <- end(xts)
    todaydate <- enddate - 86400 (I'm not sure how to get today's date here at midnight)
    todaymins <- difftime(enddate, todaydate, units="hours")
    lastavg <- xts |> utils::tail(todayhrs) |> mean(na.rm =TRUE)
```

Running this, I get

Warning: Error in ==: comparison of these types is not implemented

```
  101: Summary.difftime
  100: tail.zoo
   97: ::
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `last()` on your xts object. It can be the last `n` observations or the last period of time as a character string.

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
last(x, 3)
##                Open     High      Low    Close
## 2007-06-28 47.67604 47.70460 47.57241 47.60716
## 2007-06-29 47.63629 47.77563 47.61733 47.66471
## 2007-06-30 47.67468 47.94127 47.67468 47.76719
last(x, "1 week")
##                Open     High      Low    Close
## 2007-06-25 47.20471 47.42772 47.13405 47.42772
## 2007-06-26 47.44300 47.61611 47.44300 47.61611
## 2007-06-27 47.62323 47.71673 47.60015 47.62769
## 2007-06-28 47.67604 47.70460 47.57241 47.60716
## 2007-06-29 47.63629 47.77563 47.61733 47.66471
## 2007-06-30 47.67468 47.94127 47.67468 47.76719
```

You can subset using an IS08601 string to get everything in a range (potentially open-ended on the left or right).

```
x["2007-06-27/"]
## 2007-06-27 47.62323 47.71673 47.60015 47.62769
## 2007-06-28 47.67604 47.70460 47.57241 47.60716
## 2007-06-29 47.63629 47.77563 47.61733 47.66471
## 2007-06-30 47.67468 47.94127 47.67468 47.76719
```

Comment: I had to clean up my code. But I'm doing lastavg <- mean(last(xts, "1 day")) instead of lastavg <- xts |> utils::tail(todayhrs) |> mean(na.rm =TRUE) and I'm getting [[: subscript out of bounds

Comment: This might be a bug in `last.xts()` Are you using the [latest xts on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) (0.12.2)? You can check with `packageVersion("xts")`.

Comment: I updated from 0.12.1 but I still get the error

Comment: Ok, I used xts |> xts::last("1 day") |> mean(na.rm =TRUE), 'last' was masked. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! And yeah, masking can be a pain. Make sure to be careful about `dply::lag()` masking the `stats::lag()` generic... because that prevents any `lag()` methods from being dispatched.